# Преобразовать XML в иерархический вид со скобками

Tags: xml, c#

Здравствуйте! Скажите, есть ли такой механизм , который бы преобразовывал XML (данные обрамлены тегами) в иерархический вид, где данные обрамлены фигурными скобками. ( JSON не подходит тут). Хорошо , если бы C# был причем.

Из такого:

```
<protocols>
  <bgp>
    <group>
      <name>23</name>
      <import>policy1</import>
    </group>
   </bgp>
</protocols>
```

В такой:

```
protocols {
  bgp {
    group 23 {
      import policy1;
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: А XQuery не хотите?

Comment: Так сходу я не понял как XQuery применить! Не знакома мне технология. Но вы считаете что с помощью неё можно это преобразовать?
Прямо под мой случай!

Comment: Непонятно, у вас правила преобразования общие, или же для каждого типа узла свои? Например: чем отличается `name` от `import` внутри `group`? В XML они выглядят одинаково, в выходном формате они обрабатываются очень по-разному.

Comment: @vlazarev, можно. Наиболее вероятно, что вас заинтересует конструкция FLWOR (или как там она у нормальных людей называется).

Comment: VladD, в этом и особенность, что надо именно так такой xml переводить. Это два представления конфигураций железок juniper. Оба вида Junos принимает. Но второй вид более читабелен для человека, почему я и хочу узнать какой механизм сможет это. Создать какие-то правила. В чем это делается. Вот мне ответили, что XQuery может, ещё думаю XSLT может. Но прямо под мой случай примеров не нахожу.Есть в html, другой xml ...

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ, если заранее известна структура xml - загрузить xml в [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), пройтись по ChildNodes и записать всю необходимую информацию в StringBuilder. Решение быстрое и эффективное.

Comment: @Chaek, `XmlDocument` никогда не отличался скоростью. `XmlTextReader` должен быть в разы быстрее. Ну или взять `XPathNavigator + XPathDocument` - с ними навигация будет попроще